# How do you embed a remotely located PDF in a HTML page?

Tags: html, pdf

I need to display a PDF on a website and have it embedded inline.

The following code works if the data attribute is local, but not remote.  I just get a large grey box in place of the PDF.  I'm open to any solution as long as it works in all browsers.  We are using Rails 3 and jQuery.

```
<object data='https://remotesite.com/uploads/pdf/5/mypdf.pdf' type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='100%'>
  <p>
    It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. 
    No worries, just <a href='https://remotesite.com/uploads/pdf/5/mypdf.pdf'>click here to download the PDF file.</a>
  </p>
</object>
```

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

I tried this. works fine. just the link you supported is not OK. (I cannot reach\download that pdf other way)
But you can try this also:

```
<iframe src="http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~chong/pubs/oopsla04.pdf" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

your code worked fine with this pdf I used for the iframe.

(i tested both on chrome and internet explorer)

Comment: Well the PDF link I put in there was just an example of how it would be formatted.  They are uploaded and private and each one will be a little different.  They are just being stored on Rackspace cloud files.